# How can I open a veracrypt volume without mounting it? (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, veracrypt

I'm trying to open a veracrypt encrypted ReFS partition in linux.
Veracrypt can't open it because it can't mount 'ReFS' (I have the Paragon ReFS driver installed, but veracrypt doesn't know that).

Then I found out that I can (only) open and not mount a veracrypt partition with `zuluCrypt-cli -O /dev/sdxx -e rw`

With this I can put in my password and get this:

> SUCCESS: plain volume opened successfully

.. but I can't find a mapper to my volume (or a way to map it) anywhere. I tried to give it a name at the end of the command, but also no success.

How can I open/unlock a veracrypt partition to then use something like `sudo mount -t urefs /dev/mapper/veracrypt-vol /mnt` on it?

I'm basically looking for a command like `crypttab luksOpen ...` but my crypttab seems to only support TrueCrypt and not Veracrypt.

Comment: VeraCrypt is based on TrueCrypt and should be compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current maintainer of zuluCrypt here.

Mapper volumes are located at "/dev/mapper" and your mapper will look like "/dev/mapper/zuluCrypt-0-NAAN-sdxx-1483001985".

All released versions of zuluCrypt can not do what you want because unlocking of volumes without mounting them works ONLY with plain dm-crypt volumes and LUKS volumes.

I just added support for doing what you want with TrueCrypt and VeraCrypt volumes here[1].

If you use the git version or with version 5.3.0(to be released on Nov. 1st, 2017), you will be able to do what you want with command:

zuluCrypt-cli -O /dev/sdxx -e rw -t vcrypt

[1] https://github.com/mhogomchungu/zuluCrypt/commit/e66291577671ffd3c86540706fbf446f32c5cd40

Comment: Consider looking over the ["Style guide for questions and answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers) to ensure you understand how to write the best Q&A you can.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll check it out as soon as I have time.

Answer (score 2):

it seems to be possible in veracrypt to create the (decrypting) device mapper without mounting using the "--filesystem none" parameter